# Azure SQL reserve external IP

Tags: sql-server, azure

How can I set an Azure SQL database to have a fixed static IP?
We are using the Resource Group model - I can reserve IPs no problem and I can assign them to VMs easily but I cannot see how to assign one to a SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VM has it's private addresses translated to a publicly routable IP address at the network boundary - this is called network address translation. when you assign a public IP to an instance in the cloud what you are really doing is setting up a NAT rule. Inside the VM you continue to work and configure software as you would on a private network, so if your VM has an IP address of 192.168.1.100 then that is how SQL should be configured too. Azure will route incoming network requests to ip public IP address to it's private address. If that doen't anwer your question perhaps you can provide more details

Comment: Thanks Rob - I am talking about a SQL Server, not a VM. We have an external client that needs to create a firewall rule to access our SQL Server and requires a static external IP to do so?

Comment: ok, it's a database as a service model - you won't own an IP address for this and it is liable to change at any moment - so you clients firewall will need to access it by it's FQDN - this might be a problem for your client as it adds a bit of overhead to the connection. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/03/27/dont-rely-on-a-static-ip-address-for-your-sql-database/

Comment: Thanks Rob - I've read that article, unfortunately our client needs to create a firewall rule to allow outbound access so an FQDN is out. Are we stuck here?

Comment: yeah, his firewall will have to do a lookup going out each time - this should be doable - or if its something temporary you could lookup up the FQDN and supply the IP address - but it might break next week.

Comment: I've never come across a firewall that will allow an FQDN based rule?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: in most firewalls it a global config rule and in all the ones i've seen it's disabled. checkpoins, fortinets, sonicwall - it has to poll the dns server to look for any changes. http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD37062

Comment: Great, thanks Rob. Firewall is a Fortinet AFAIK so fingers crossed.